# responsive top bar search box in mobile search button problem

Tags: php, css, responsive

I followed a guide on the internet to implement a search bar on top of my navigation bar and responsive, but i have a problem when viewing with mobile, my search box button is at below of my search box.

something like this.
[image]

here is my code in HTML

```html
<div class="search-container">
    <form action="/">
         <input type="text" placeholder="seach..." name="search">
         <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and my css

```css
    .topnav .search-container {
      float: right;
    }
    
    .topnav input[type=text] {
      padding: 6px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .topnav .search-container button {
      float: right;
      padding: 6px 10px;
      margin-top: 8px;
      margin-right: 16px;
      background: #ddd;
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .topnav .search-container button:hover {
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav .search-container {
        float: none;
      }
      .topnav a, .topnav span, .topnav input[type=text], .topnav .search-container button {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 14px;
      }
      .topnav input[type=text] {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;  
      }
```

How can I make the button in mobile view to be at the same row beside at right of my search box?

Comment: Why don't you add the CSS for button too.

Comment: Or use display flex to keep in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: block;` makes both input and button "put newline after", also they both are `width: 100%;` which is bad for both elements, if you make them inline-block *(they already are by default)* and set width that both fits, they be next to each other.

For example like this:

```css
body, html { /* just example */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.topnav:after { /* clearfix so the .topnav container keeps its size properly */
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  /* no need for float: right; here, you can comment-out the whitespace in html */
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  /* non-flex version require harcoded width (unless you correct it with javascript) */
  width: 40px;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }

  .topnav .search-container input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 14px;
    /* padding (left+right), border (left+right), button width */
    width: calc(100% - 28px - 2px - 40px);
    /* bit easier like that: */
    /* 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    */
  }
  
  .topnav .search-container button {
    margin-right: 0;
    /* correcting height difference between input[type=text] with border and button without border */
    padding: 15px 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/">
      <input type="text" placeholder="seach..." name="search"><!--
      --><button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search">...</i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is major disadvantage with that aproach and that is the need of hardcoded width of button.

Another way is to use `position: absolute;`, old fashion but simple, for example like this:

```js
// little demonstation of variable width
var times = 4;
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('button>i').innerText = '.'.repeat(times++);
  if(times>6){ times = 3; }
}, 1000);
```

```css
body, html { /* just example */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.topnav:after { /* clearfix so the .topnav container keeps its size properly */
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  /* no need for float: right; here, you can comment-out the whitespace in html */
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }

  .topnav .search-container input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .topnav .search-container button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    /* correcting height difference between input[type=text] with border and button without border */
    padding: 15px 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/">
      <input type="text" placeholder="seach..." name="search"><!--
      --><button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search">...</i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use flex-box, which is modern and more flexible, for example like this:

```js
// little demonstation of variable width
var times = 4;
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('button>i').innerText = '.'.repeat(times++);
  if(times>6){ times = 3; }
}, 1000);
```

```css
body, html {  /* just example */
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.topnav:after { /* clearfix so the .topnav container keeps its size properly */
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

/* following two blocks are most imporant */
.topnav .search-container form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.topnav .search-container input[type=text] {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  /* no need for float: right; here, you can comment-out the whitespace in html */
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  /* no need for hardcoded width */
}

.topnav .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  
  .topnav .search-container input[type=text]   {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  
  .topnav .search-container button {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 14px; /* height is automatically corrected by flex */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/">
      <input type="text" placeholder="seach..." name="search"><!--
      --><button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search">...</i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```